# In ruby/rails, how do I sort on a date value where the date can sometimes be null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to sort my games by game_date, but sometimes the game_date may be null, and I will get an exception: undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass

```
@games = @teams.reduce([]) { |memo, team| memo + team.games }.sort_by(&:game_date)
```

Any good way of doing this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you just want to drop entries without date, simplest solution -

```
ar.select(&:date).sort_by(&:date)
```

adding nils at the end can be done with

```
ar.select(&:date).sort_by(&:date) + ar.reject(&:date)
```

If you happen to know the range of possible dates, you can be fine with something like

```
ar.sort_by{|e| e.date || Date.new(9999)}
```

BTW, reduce in your statement can be changed to (IMHO) more clear

```
@games = @teams.map(&:games).flatten
```

Comment: thanks. What if I didnt want to drop them but just put them at the end?

Answer (score 4):

An easy way would be to split your array into those with `nil`s and those without, then sort the non-nil half as desired and paste them together:

```
parts  = a.partition { |o| o.date.nil? }
sorted = parts.last.sort_by(&:date) + parts.first
```

This approach will work with any method (i.e. not just with `date`) and it should be quick enough.

Comment: My answer does this in one step. And keeps all the values.

Comment: @CantGetANick: This approach doesn't lose any values either, I'm not sure what you mean by that. It also works.