# Ruby sort by (integer) "comparison of NilClass with 3200 failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I want to sort my records in an rails application:

```
@ebms = Ebm.all
@ebms.sort_by! {|u| u.number}
```

The `u.number` is defined as integer!
The problem is that Rails cannot compare it with `nil`:

```
comparison of NilClass with 32400 failed
```

What can i do to evade this error?

Comment: Is `number` a field in the database?

Comment: To avoid this problem in the future, you may wish to add validation to the model to make sure that records without a `number` attribute cannot be created (if this makes sense for your application).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about to try convert nil to integer?

```
   @ebms = Ebm.all
   @ebms.sort_by! { |u| u.number.to_i }
```

Comment: does it make any sense

Comment: It makes sense, but is not much different from Matt's answer, which was earlier. It is a slightly better way of writing, though.

Comment: This problem also occurred at `min_by` and there i prefer Matts answer.

Answer (score 22):

You can add a default value for the comparison that will be used when `number` is nil:

```
@ebms = Ebm.all
@ebms.sort_by! {|u| u.number || 0}
```

Or you can follow the suggestions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8738207/385532) to select those with a number and sort them, then add those without a number to the list.

Comment: Depending on whether the OP's need the default could be a very small number of a very large number.

Comment: What if some `u.number` return a negative number?

Comment: @toro2k In such case, if the OP wants the nil cases to be sorted first, then the default should be `-Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: or you can be excplicit about the way you sort by nil values by wrapping them inside an array: `sort_by! {|u| [u.nil?.to_i, u.number || 0]}`. Arrays are first sorted by first, then by second values, etc.