# Rails - How to make blank/null values come last when sorting ascending(active record)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, activeadmin

Good morning.

I have a little problem.

In my project in Active Admin, I'm trying to sort a column which has the date time datatype and logically the blank/null values should come last , which in my case it doesn't happen this way.

For example, my first 2 pages after sorting are working fine, then the sorting for the last pages is without sense.

```
    column :booked_test_date, :sortable => 'last_test_pos_processing_orders.booked_test_date'
```

Comment: Any hints, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738155/in-ruby-rails-how-do-i-sort-on-a-date-value-where-the-date-can-sometimes-be-nul

Comment: Thanks. I will check it and let you know with the outcome.